# SQL: Find and Replace with SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a MySQL InnoDB database.

I have a column my in '`article`' table called `url` that needs to be updated.

Stored in `article.url =`

```
/blog/2010/article-name
/blog/1998/the-article-name
/blog/...
```

I need to change *`/blog/`* to *`/news/`*. (E.g. now article.url = '/news/...')

What is the SQL needed to replace *"/blog/"* with *"/news/"* in the **article.url** column?

Answer (score 4):

```
update url
set article = replace(article, '/blog/', '/news/')
where article like '/blog/%'
```

Comment: This may give you problems if there is a `/blog/` in the middle of an article url.

Comment: Was just adding the `where` clause as you typed that.

Comment: @ar, I don't believe so since Red Filter only put a % on the right side and not left side as well

Comment: But that would still change /blog/foo/blog/bar to /news/foo/news/bar not /news/foo/blog/bar. You could use `set article = '/news/' + substring(article, 7)` instead, maybe also `where article like '/blog/%' and len(article) >= 7` just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If every url starts with "/blog/" and you don't want to change anything except the prefix, then you can just use substring() and concat() instead of replace():

```
update article
set url = concat('/news/',substring(url,7))
where url like '/blog/%';
```

Comment: @Erik8: "7" is the starting position for the substring: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: But doesn't that assume that *all* url's in my database start with "/blog".  What happens if I have in my database a url that starts with "/xyz/"?

Comment: @Erik8: If a url starts with "/xyz/" then it won't match the where clause and therefore will not be updated, which I assume is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to replace a string within MySQL on the fly, but the field could contain 2 items. So I wrapped a `REPLACE()` within a `REPLACE()`, such as:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(field_name, “what we are looking for”, “replace first instance”), 
       “something else we are looking for”, “replace second instance”)
```

This is the syntax I used to detect a boolean value:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(field, 1, “Yes”), 0, “No”)
```

Hope this helps!